# Driver not found using crystal reports with [ucanaccess] jdbc driver

Tags: crystal-reports, report, ucanaccess

How can I use Crystal Reports with ucanaccess jdbc driver?  I'm getting "Driver not found" error.  I copied the ucanaccess jar file to Business objects in program files (C:\Program Files (x86)\Business Objects\Common\3.5\java), edited CRConfig.xml file and already had JDBC (JNDI) configured in Crystal Reports.  MySQL, JTDS, Oracle and SQLite drivers work fine.

Answer (score 0):

UCanAccess has dependencies - HSQLDB and Jackcess, with additional Jackcess dependencies - so the UCanAccess driver is more than just the "ucanaccess jar" file itself. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21955257/2144390) for details on the other jar files you will need to make available to Crystal Reports if you want to use UCanAccess.

Comment: I already added all jars to Classpath in the CRConfig.xml file.  No luck.